# Create a helplink attribute for a .net library to display in visual studio where my library is added as a reference

Tags: c#, attributes

I have created a small library in c# and want to display a help url like

```
class HelpURL : Attribute
{
    string url;
    public HelpURL(string url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }
}

[HelpURL("www.example.com")]
public func() {
    ...
}
```

It works inside my library project but i dont know how to display it in another project where my library is added as a reference? How can i do that?

**Edit** I tried using XML comments but dont see any changes.

[image]

Comment: You need to call the function by an instance which includes the namespace.class.method().  And you need to put a using statement at top of module.  So a standard microsoft library like System.Net is a namespace.  So you need a constructor to the class like MyNamespace.HelpURL url = new MyNamespace.HelpURL();  Then call method with url.func();

Comment: Hi @jdweng, thank you but unfortunately i dont completely understand your comment, maybe you could add it as an answer including a small example?

Comment: Manager constructor does not have a parameter.  Why are you using a 1?

Comment: I tried to trigger an exception. It already works, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use Visual Studio's built-in intellisense features instead. All you need to do is add [XML documentation comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to your code, and it will automatically be visible in your other projects.

Comment: I tried but cant see any difference, i have added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: Make sure you recompile your library.

Comment: Make sure you build the documentation file: Project Properties -> Build Tab -> Output section -> Check "XML documentation file"